# what is the right webpack configuration for scss files with style, css and sass loader

Tags: reactjs, sass, webpack-4

> at first i was getting error that scss files are not readable, when i tried to add options for sass loader to set its path to node_modules. But after that i could not solve this error. Is there anyother way to add multiple loaders and options for them? 
>   **this is my webpack.config.js"**

````
var webpack = require('webpack');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
var ExtractText = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/src/js/index'),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/dist'),
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({
      path: __dirname,
      filename: 'webpack-stats.json'
    }),
    new ExtractText({
      filename: '[name]-[hash].css'
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use:[{
          loader: "sass-loader",
          options: {
              "includePaths": [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
              ]
            }
            },
          {
            loader: "style-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader"
          }
          ]
      },
    ],
  },
};```[this is the error i am getting][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O8ct.png
````

Comment: `{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
}`

Comment: Thankyou, I have tried this. now i am getting this error Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
       SassError: File to import not found or unreadable: @material/elevation/mixins.
                on line 23 of node_modules/@material/card/_mixins.scss
               from line 23 of node_modules/@material/card/mdc-card.scss
              from line 23 of node_modules/@material/react-card/index.scss
                from line 2 of /tmp/build_8663a9ab7ca425b4dba37090160b2ed2/assets/src/scss/index.scss
      >> @import "@material/elevation/mixins";

Comment: @SerhiiPuchkovskyi can you please look at it again.